# how do we find unique pairs in an array?

Tags: arrays

Find all unique pairs of the element in an array that sum to S. Forex. If array = {2,4,6,4,6} and S = 8 then answer is {(2,6), (4,4)}.I know a solution to print all the pairs in the array but how do we print unique pairs?

Comment: well, if you know how to get all the pairs, then you can just put these pairs into `Set`, since by definition set only contains unique elements

Comment: If all you need to know is how to go from a list to a set (with duplicate items removed), almost every language will have a very straightforward way to do that. If you added a language tag, such an answer (or an existing Q&A entry) for that language could be found. Right now, we don't know if you want an answer for Fortran, C, Java, Clojure, Erlang...; as such, it's almost definitionally too broad to answer (as folks can't know which answer is closest to your needs, and thus which one to vote for, without knowing more about what those needs are).

Comment: In the future -- including your existing code in a question is generally a good way to ensure that an answer is focused and useful (and would define the language implicitly, letting someone else edit in an appropriate language tag in the case like this where that tag was forgotten).

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of it. Hope it helps. Works in python.

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
S = 6
pairs = []

shift = 0
for i in array:
    shift += 1
    for j in array[shift:]:
        if S == (i+j):
            if (i,j) not in pairs and (j,i) not in pairs:
                pairs.append((i,j))
print pairs
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were looking for some different syntax or approach, but i'm sure that there should be a couple lambda expression solutions that should get the answer to your problem in a fancier way.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
pairs = []
append_flag = True
S = 6

for index1, element1 in enumerate(a):
  for index2, element2 in enumerate(a):
    if index1 != index2 and (element1 + element2) == S:
      append_flag = True
      for p in pairs:
        if ( (p[1] == element1 and p[0] == element2) or (p[0] == element1 and p[1] == element2) ):
         append_flag = False      
      if append_flag:
        pairs.append( [element1,element2] )

print pairs
```

This works on python

Comment: This is **really** unnecessarily slow, when other (set- or dict-based solutions -- or ones that sort the inputs and rely on that sort order for guarantees) would rely on an O(1) check for preexisting presence rather than needing to iterate over the existing list of potential outputs; such iteration when done inside a loop changes linear time to exponential.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could give a better answer to this question, I'm always willing to learn. How would you do this using python?

Comment: I'm on the close vote for this question -- I don't believe it should be answered here *at all* without improvements/clarifications first, as described in comments above. Should those take place, though, I'll be glad to add a competing answer.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation in `java` contains sort at the beginning and find an elemens without comparing it.

```
public final class Pair {

    private final int first;
    private final int second;

    public Pair(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

}

public static List<Pair> findUniquePairs(int[] arr, int s) {
    List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= s)
            break;

        Set<Integer> tmp = new HashSet<>();

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] >= s)
                break;
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] != s || tmp.contains(arr[j]))
                continue;
            tmp.add(arr[j]);
            pairs.add(new Pair(arr[i], arr[j]));
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```